# Could not create an acl object: Invalid XML

Tags: admin, magento2.2, error, acl

I'm a newbie learning and got this **message** when **installing a theme** and trying to access to **admin**, would someone mind giving me a hand?

I got this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid XML in file /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Plazathemes/Themeoptions/etc/acl.xml:
Element 'resource', attribute 'id': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not accepted by the pattern '([A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){1,}_[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]{1,}::[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,}'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeId'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': Warning: No precomputed value available, the value was either invalid or something strange happend.
Line: 21


Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid XML in file /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Plazathemes/Themeoptions/etc/acl.xml:
Element 'resource', attribute 'id': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not accepted by the pattern '([A-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}){1,}_[A-Z]+[A-Z0-9a-z]{1,}::[A-Za-z_0-9]{1,}'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': 'plazathemes_themeoptions::config' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'typeId'.
Line: 21

Element 'resource', attribute 'id': Warning: No precomputed value available, the value was either invalid or something strange happend.
Line: 21

#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()
#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(227): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Session/Interceptor.php(102): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(159): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session\Interceptor->processLogin()
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('mainaccess', 'J7k-vVZ-czW-ESr')
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent('login', Array)
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('mainaccess', 'J7k-vVZ-czW-ESr')
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(78): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', Array, Array)
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('mainaccess', 'J7k-vVZ-czW-ESr')
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#17 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#20 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#21 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#22 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#23 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first letter of the permission and the first letter after the underscore MUST be uppercase. Just change `plazathemes_themeoptions::config` into `Plazathemes_Themeoptions::config` and you should be fine.

In general, module names should follow the convention `<Vendor>_<ModuleName>` (note that this is upper camelcase) in any place where they are used.